# How to add my own attributes which will be updated by FabricJS modification function?

Tags: fabricjs

What attributes have changed when an object has been modified (moved, scaled, rotated) in FabricJS?
I understand that Left and Top for sure, but I'm curious if there is a way to provide my own attribute, for example, X and Y?

Basically, what I need is to update X and Y anytime Left and Top were changed... Kind of observing on Left and Top...

Tnx

Comment: move > (left &top), scaled > (scaleX,scaleY), rotate > (left,top,angle) attributes are changing. What you want actually?

Comment: i think you should be more explict on what are you trying to solve. if you want to observer top and left you have to catch moving, scaling, rotating, skewing. is this a previous form of the question with red and yellow shape?